# is there a batch request api for HERE maps routing?

Tags: here-api

The documentation shows how to submit a batch request to the [geocoder api](https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/dev_guide/topics/submit-batch-request.html). Is there also a documentation for sending batch requests to the routing api so that I can send several start/destination waypoints at once?

Comment: Have you looked at the Fleet Telematics API? https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/topics/use-cases.html

Comment: yes, but if I am not mistaking I can only add additional waypoints for a route

Answer (score -1):

The [Matrix routing API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/routing/many-to-many-matrix-routing) is exactly what you want. In this example the matrix routing calculates all combinations between 3 start points and 5 destination points. Here is the request taken from the example:

`https://matrix.route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.json?start0=52.5139%2C13.3576&start1=52.5214%2C13.4155&start2=52.5253%2C13.3693&destination0=52.5411%2C13.2127&destination1=52.5163%2C13.3780&destination2=52.4920%2C13.2849&destination3=52.4987%2C13.5228&destination4=52.5547%2C13.4578&mode=fastest%3Bcar&summaryattributes=all&apiKey=YOUR_API_KEY`

The response contains 15 route summaries which contain distance, travelTime, costFactor and routeId. `RouteId` can be later used for getting directions or/and route shape for the selected route.

Comment: no, it is not exactly what I want. I don't want a distance matrix. I want a batch routing request. As HERE Developer Support confirmed (see below) currently there is no HERE product that supports 1-1 batch routing.

Comment: @hatRat got it. Sorry for misunderstanding.